# DNS and accessing my domain's web site from an internal network

Tags: networking, dns

I have recently purchased a domain name, we'll call it `domain.suffix`. On the LAN, I have an Active Directory subdomain called `directory.domain.suffix`. I have a website set up on a Windows Nano Server with IIS (a member of the Active Directory domain) named `webserver.directory.domain.suffix`.

From the Internet, I'm able to access the website using either `domain.suffix`, or `www.domain.suffix`. From within the LAN though, I'm only able to access it using `www.domain.suffix`.

From my ISP, I have 5 static usable public IP addresses: let's call them as follows:

`100.0.0.1` `100.0.0.2` `100.0.0.3` `100.0.0.4` `100.0.0.5`

On my LAN, I have `192.168.0.1` for the router and `192.168.0.2` for the web server.

My pfSense router and firewall is using public IP address `100.0.0.1`. Using a virtual IP and port forwarding rule in pfSense, HTTP traffic for public IP `100.0.0.2` is routed to the web server, which is local IP `192.168.0.2`.

I am using Active Directory DNS, but it's not linked to the domain name provider's DNS server, so this is for name resolution for the LAN. Under `domain.suffix`, I have only two records: a Host (A) record pointing all LAN requests to `*.domain.suffix` to public IP address `100.0.0.2` (the web server). The one Alias (CNAME) record sends all LAN requests for `www.domain.suffix` to the host `webserver.directory.domain.suffix`. Again, Active Directory is using the `directory` subdomain.

So my question is, how can I access the web site from LAN hosts through both `www.domain.suffix` and `domain.suffix`?

Answer (score 0):

dns entries has nothing to do with access to your web site from an internal network.

the dns server translate a domainname to an ip address

```
ping yourdomain.com
```

will give you:

```
PING yourdomain.com (69.172.201.153): 56 data bytes
```

whether your webserver will listen to your ip address is something else, check the IIS manual for that.

Make sure that http://192.168.0.2/ will work from your lan first, then you can configure your router to forward internet access traffic to your IIS server.

Comment: As it is now, `http(s)://192.168.0.2` is accessible from inside the LAN. Internet traffic is being forwarded to the IIS server, and using URL Rewrite, I'm redirecting to `https://www.domain.suffix`. Pinging `domain.suffix` doesn't work (could not find the host) from within the LAN, whereas pinging `www.domain.suffix` does work.

Comment: Then you should "tell" your pfSense router/firewall to forward the traffic from it's public IP addresses (100.0.x.x) to 192.168.0.2.  Maybe this guide (first google hit) can help: https://turbofuture.com/computers/Port-Forwarding-in-pfSense-How-to-Configure-NAT